# How to add <p> tags around text nodes using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following XML document

```html
<body>
  <h2>title</h2>
  some text and a <a href="link">link</a> here.
</body>
```

I want to transform this using XSLT into:

```html
<body>
  <h2>title</h2>
  <p>some text and a <a href="link">link</a> here.</p>
</body>
```

Therefore I tried the following XSLT:

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" method="xml" cdata-section-elements="script"/>
  <xsl:template match="/ | node() | @*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="body/text()" >
    <p><xsl:copy/></p>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But that doesn't seem to give the expected result (it works fine if the text node does not contain the anchor element). So any idea of how to accomplish this with XSLT? (I do have the option to parse the XML using C# later on, but my initial idea was to use XSLT)

### Update

To make the overall requirements a bit more clear, the input XML (or actually XHTML) is not fixed, it can be anything as it is user input. Really the only thing I can expect from it, is that it will be valid XML (XHTML) and that some lines might not be wrapped in a `<p>` tag .

Comment: Eventually, I don't think you'll be able to avoid specifying either a list of elements (children of body) that need to be handled on their own (e.g. `<h2>` in your example), or a list of elements (children of body) that need to wrapped in a `<p>` element together with the surrounding text nodes (e.g. `<a>` in your example).

Comment: @michael.hor257k yeah I was already aware that this isn't a simple problem, hence the reason why I asked it here ;). All your help and suggestions are definitely appreciated btw.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="body">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select=" @*|*[not(self::a)]"/>
        <p><xsl:copy-of select="text()|a"/></p>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: I can see that working on my given input, but I'm afraid it's not generic enough to match all the requirements (which I didn't make clear enough in my question indeed).

Comment: @BartKoopman We can only work with what you give us. In any case, I don't think you can make this truly generic - see the comment I have added to your question. However, you *can* expand the second template by adding more elements to the exception and subtracting them from the rule.

Comment: Fair enough, your answer indeed showed me that my question wasn't clear enough, and I already expected it wouldn't get a simple straight forward answer (unless I missed something obvious myself).

Answer (score 1):

This is slightly more complex than just "adding `p` tags around text nodes" because in your example you're actually trying to add one `p` tag around a group of three nodes - two text nodes and one intervening element node.  For your specific example the following would work

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <body>
      <xsl:copy-of select="body/h2" />
      <p>
        <xsl:copy-of select="body/h2/following-sibling::node()" />         
      </p>
    </body>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

but that's obviously not very generic.  More generally, if you want to wrap everything between one `h2` and the next in a single `p` then you can use a variation on the "Muenchian grouping" method - use a `key` to associate each non-h2 node with its nearest preceding-sibling `h2`

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:key name="groupByHeader" match="node()[not(self::h2)]"
           use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::h2[1])" />

  <xsl:template match="body">
    <xsl:copy>
      <!-- everything before the first h2 -->
      <xsl:copy-of select="key('groupByHeader', '')" />
      <xsl:apply-templates select="h2" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="h2">
    <!-- this h2 -->
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    <!-- everything between this h2 and the next one (or the end of body) -->
    <p><xsl:copy-of select="key('groupByHeader', generate-id())" /></p>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

On your sample input these two stylesheets should both produce the same output:

```
<body><h2>title</h2><p>
  some text and a <a href="link">link</a> here.
</p></body>
```

If you need the indentation to precisely match your "expected output" then it gets even hairier as you essentially need to split the first text node in two, putting the leading whitespace before the opening `p` tag and the rest of the text node after it, and similarly with the last text node.  You can't simply `normalize-space()` on each text node because that would strip out spaces you *do* need to keep - you don't want to end up with

```
<p>some text and a<a href="link">link</a>here.</p>
```

Comment: Indentation is not important, it's XML (or actually XHTML), but the tricky part is indeed what input is expected, since the `h2` can also be a bunch of different tags. And worse it could be that we have  lines which do have `p` tags around them already. Still I think I can get a lot further with your two templates, thx.

Answer (score -5):

Try this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" method="xml" cdata-section-elements="script"/>
  <xsl:template match="/ | node() | @*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="body" >
    <p><xsl:copy-of select="."/></p>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: that would wrap everything in a single `<p>` tag and make the output invalid.